# RadioButtonList SelectedItem returns NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this `RadioButton` but it doesn't return a value, is always `null` or empty.

The radio is this one:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblParcelamento" runat="server"/>
```

I fill the `RadioButtonList` with this:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    if (decimal.Parse(txtValorTotal.InnerHtml) < 500)
    {
        string val = string.Format("{0:#.00}", Convert.ToDouble(txtValorTotal.InnerHtml) * 0.987);
        rblParcelamento.Items.Add(new ListItem("1 x " + string.Format("{0:#.00}", val) + " - Prazo: 7 dias", "1"));
    }
    else
    {
        string val = string.Format("{0:#.00}", Convert.ToDouble(txtValorTotal.InnerHtml) * 0.987);
        rblParcelamento.Items.Add(new ListItem("1 x " + string.Format("{0:#.00}", val) + " - Prazo: 28 dias", "1"));
    }
    if (decimal.Parse(txtValorTotal.InnerHtml) >= 1000)
    {
        string val = string.Format("{0:#.00}", decimal.Parse(txtValorTotal.InnerHtml) / 2);
        rblParcelamento.Items.Add(new ListItem("2 x " + val + " - Prazo: 21/35 ddl", "2"));
    }
    if (decimal.Parse(txtValorTotal.InnerHtml) >= 1500)
    {
        string val = string.Format("{0:#.00}", decimal.Parse(txtValorTotal.InnerHtml) / 3);
        rblParcelamento.Items.Add(new ListItem("3 x " + val + " - Prazo: 21/28/35 ddl", "3"));
    }
    if (decimal.Parse(txtValorTotal.InnerHtml) >= 2000)
    {
        string val = string.Format("{0:#.00}", decimal.Parse(txtValorTotal.InnerHtml) / 4);
        rblParcelamento.Items.Add(new ListItem("4 x " + val + " - Prazo: 21/28/35/42 ddl", "4"));
    }
}
```

When I try to catch like this `rblParcelamento.SelectedItem.Value` returns null and `rblParcelamento.SelectedValue` is empty.

Comment: Could you post your code for `txtValorTotal`?

Comment: @FF- it's just the price of the cart (it's a e-commerce)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is because you are not selecting anything on your `RadioButtonList`.

You either need to select it first with `SelectedIndex`.`SelectedValue`, `SelectedItem` or getting the value after the user selects it.

Try this, assuming you want to use your `rblParcelamento.SelectedItem.Value` after setting its value:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    decimal total = decimal.Parse(txtValorTotal.InnerHtml);

    if (total < 500)
    {
        string val = string.Format("{0:#.00}", Convert.ToDouble(total) * 0.987);
        rblParcelamento.Items.Add(new ListItem("1 x " + string.Format("{0:#.00}", val) + " - Prazo: 7 dias", "1"));
    }
    else
    {
        string val = string.Format("{0:#.00}", Convert.ToDouble(total) * 0.987);
        rblParcelamento.Items.Add(new ListItem("1 x " + string.Format("{0:#.00}", val) + " - Prazo: 28 dias", "1"));
    }

    if (total >= 1000)
    {
        string val = string.Format("{0:#.00}", total / 2);
        rblParcelamento.Items.Add(new ListItem("2 x " + val + " - Prazo: 21/35 ddl", "2"));
    }

    if (total >= 1500)
    {
        string val = string.Format("{0:#.00}", total / 3);
        rblParcelamento.Items.Add(new ListItem("3 x " + val + " - Prazo: 21/28/35 ddl", "3"));
    }

    if (total >= 2000)
    {
        string val = string.Format("{0:#.00}", total / 4);
        rblParcelamento.Items.Add(new ListItem("4 x " + val + " - Prazo: 21/28/35/42 ddl", "4"));
    }

    rblParcelamento.SelectedIndex = 0; //you first need to select your item, in this case, the first one

    //rblParcelamento.SelectedValue = "1"; //this also works

    //rblParcelamento.SelectedItem => this could work if you save a variable with (new ListItem)
}

string rblValue = rblParcelamento.SelectedItem.Value; //then you can get the value of the selected item
```

Comment: Thanks but still not working, tried the three ways, i also tried to replace `(!IsPostBack)`to `(IsPostBack)`, and always return "1"

Comment: If it is always returning "1", then is probably becuase of the value on `txtValorTotal`, which is used on `if (total < 500)`. I don't know how else i can help you, your question was about why you were getting `null` on `rblParcelamento.SelectedItem.Value`